# Approval for iOS app store reviews?

Tags: applications, app-store-connect

Apps have solicited my input, so after spending time to make a review, it seems my reviews are not posted.

Do reviews submitted for Apps have to be approved by either the developer or Apple?

Comment: I'm editing out the "why" since that's off topic here. There's good reason to answer the what and how, though. Also - are you waiting a week between review submission and checking or are you expecting things to show up within 48 hours? I'm not aware of Apple saying they publish even a fraction of the reviews that get entered. My guess is algorithms and spot checking by humans is involved, but that's just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reviews submitted apps must be approved by Apple, in order to make sure that there it's not spam or contains swear words or such.

The reason that you are unable to see your comments, is likely that you have to wait awhile. Devs **don't** get to pick which reviews are down and which aren't. Also, if your review was for an earlier version, it, obviously, won't appear in "Current Version Only".

Comment: Since you edited I'll comment delete... Less confusing